# Return files with the same size from a list

Tags: c#, linq

Lets say I have 5 files

- F1: 1MBs
- F2: 1MBs
- F3: 5MBs
- F4: 5MBs
- F5: 7MBs

How can I return files with matching sizes, so the new list will have F1, 2, 3, 4 but not F5?

To get these files from a folder I tried:

```
 var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(directoryPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                      .GroupBy(s1 => new FileInfo(s1).Length)
                      .SelectMany(grp => grp.Skip(1));
```

Comment: What is the *criterium* you use to exclude the `F5`? Do you want to remove all 7MB files? The file with the *biggest size*, something else?

Comment: Are you looking for files that have at least one more file with the same size?

Comment: @Guy yes, I'm doing this to improve an algorithm that deleted duplicated files, so instead of hashing every file found, i want to hash and compare files who's size matches

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Then they aren't copies of each other. I'm only looking for identical duplicates

Comment: You know that same file size doesn't necessarily means duplicate?

Comment: @Guy Yes I know, you could have a 3Mb image and a 3Mb text file, but also duplicate files are always equal in size right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to add a `Where` on the group's count:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(directoryPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                     .GroupBy(i=> new FileInfo(i).Length)
                     .Where(g=> g.Count() > 1)
                     .SelectMany(g => g);
```